# How to get Google maps query results with API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a simple google maps query to work with the API. All I want to do is get JSON for the foodbanks around Denver.  So far I have:

```
var gm_api_key = "apikeyhere";

// return locations for foodbanks in denver
var denver_lat_long = '39.7392,-104.9903';
var loc = denver_lat_long;
var query_str_foodbank = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?query=food+bank&location=' + loc + '&radius=500&key=' + gm_api_key;

// return locations for thrift shops (e.g. goodwill) in denver


// nodejs implementation
var resp = "";
var request = require('request');
var req = request(query_str_foodbank, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    resp = body;
    //console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
});

var food_bank_json = JSON.parse(resp);
```

It just returns a bunch of irrelevant stuff like 'post office', etc.  It doesn't seem to be actually using the `query`.

Comment: `console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.` - well, that doesn't seem right, you should be getting some json data there

Comment: Try `name=food+bank` instead of `query=food+bank`

Comment: your next problem will be `var food_bank_json = JSON.parse(resp);` - as that will run before the `request` even begins

Comment: Yeah, I'm just prototyping it in a nodejs console so I was running the `var food_bank_json = JSON.parse(resp);` after everything else was done

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problems were twofold: one, the `keyword` or `name` arg is the correct one to use here, not `query` that I would expect to use.  Two, the `radius` parameter is in meters, so for around 100 miles it would need to be about 150000.  A correct page call should be:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&keyword=food+bank&location=39.7392,-104.9903&radius=150000&key=apikeyhere